# Is it possible to upload files other then images with php and <input type="file">

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm using this code to upload files:

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = "";
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if (isset($_FILES["file"])) {
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "xls" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" && $imageFileType != "JPG") {
     $uploadOk = 0;
}
```

But when I tried to upload an .xls file it didn't upload to the specified map.
Is this only for images? If yes, is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

`<input type=file>` works for all file types, since it is just uploading the raw file bytes as-is. PHP accepts all files, [within configurable limits](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php). There is no reason for an xls file to not upload, unless it is exceeding the server's filesize limits. It is the responsibility of the PHP script to filter accepted uploaded data as needed.

Answer (score 0):

of course you can! you can upload any file you wish(extension doesn't matter). maybe you should read this to be more clear [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, you can upload a xls file with .
As far i can see your given code is fine. So, you can add a check for verifying its mime type to double ensure whether you are uploading a correct file.